# Why won't Swift Playgrounds show a view's transform?

Tags: swift, rotation, cgaffinetransform, swift-playground

For example, this code just shows a rectangle unrotated in a Playground

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 150))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 3))
```

[image]

When it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please show your _entire_ playground code for this example.

Comment: @matt Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playground is giving you a preview of the view, not rendering it within another view.  The transform property only affects the presentation layer of the view and not its actual bounds.  If you want to see the transform add your transformed view to the playgrounds live view and look in the assistant editor on the right.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 150))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 3))
let rootView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
rootView.addSubview(view)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rootView
```